# Bootstrap Image expand outside of column container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, styles

Hi I am looking to have an image in a column however have it go full width through CSS.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class= "col-md-3">
NAV HERE
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<p>Some test</p>
<img SHOULD BE FULL PAGE WITH like container-fuild class />
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
<img src="xyz.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"    width="100%" height="auto">
```